# Why setTitleEdgeInsets not working iOS 13? Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios13

I have custom profile UIButton that have image and user profile name title. I'm setting image and title of button and also setting title and image edge inset. Before iOS 13 my code was working perfect but at iOS 13 devices setTitleEdgeInsets not working. When I did debug, title inset value is true but button not setting the value that I give. You can find the code and the screen shot below.

[image: Text should be left of image.]

```
@implementation NYTProfileButton
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.height);

self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2;

UIEdgeInsets imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width - self.frame.size.height);
self.imageEdgeInsets = imageInsets;

UIEdgeInsets titleInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, self.frame.size.height-self.imageView.image.size.height+5.0, 0, 0);
self.titleEdgeInsets = titleInsets;
[self setTitleEdgeInsets:titleInsets];
 }

 - (void)awakeFromNib
{
 self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
 }

 @end
```

Comment: self.titleEdgeInsets = titleInset just sets the insets to the property titleEdgeInsets unless this is inside a subclass of UIButton which it doesn't seem like it is, you need to show the full code of what class you're subclassing. show the full code

Comment: This is a subclass of UIButton, I've add full code. @Loxx

Comment: i see, i'll check it out soon to see if i can help, thanks

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a UIButton that has both `titleEdgeInsets` and `imageEdgeInsets`, the title was correctly positioned before iOS 13 but now is offset to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The image insets were not working for me for iOS 13.

Though I did not fix the issue but found a work around which might be useful.

For me the image was not visible hence I added a UIImage subview to the button in which I wanted to display the image.(For your case you can add UILabel Subview at the required position)

Code I added to display my image correctly:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *){

     let advanceSearchChevronImage = UIImage(named: "General/chevronUp")
     advanceSearchChevronImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.width - 50, y: 0, width: 50.0, height: advanceSearchButton.bounds.height))
     advanceSearchChevronImageView.contentMode = .center
     advanceSearchChevronImageView.image = advanceSearchChevronImage
     advanceSearchButton.addSubview(advanceSearchChevronImageView)
}
```

For your case you can give ""(empty string) as value for the button Title. Add a label to this button as a subview and position it as required by you.
Make these changes only when iOS 13.

Hope you can take some clue from this and get solution to the problem you are facing - if you are looking for a very quick fix.